# Hexagons share interior points

Tags: geometry, combinatorial-geometry

Can we draw infinitely many hexagons, not necessarily convex, on the plane so that any three of them share a common interior point, but no four of them does? For four hexagons this is possible, using concavity to get the fourth hexagon to avoid the area when the other three overlap but hitting the area where any pair overlap.